# When using an SSH jumpbox, is it possible to defer to the jumpbox for authentication?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am connecting to a private SSH server by way of a jumpbox. Unfortunately, this requires me to put my public key on all of the private servers since the authentication is still resolved from my local machine.

The jump box already has keys setup to access all of the private servers. Is there a way to use the jumpbox’s authentication resolution instead of my own local machine?

Comment: Interesting question. So are you using `ssh -A` to connect so you forwarding of the authentication agent connection and instead of you doing that you want the equivalent of `ssh -A` for the jumpbox connection? Or are you using `ssh -J`?

Comment: I'm using -J to select the jump box and no other options.

Comment: Try using `ssh -AJ` and see of that does it.

Comment: My understanding of -A is that it takes my local authentication agent and exposes it in the ssh connection.  But that's actually the opposite of what I'm needing.  I need the jump box's authentication agent to be used instead of my local one.

Comment: Got it! Hopefully someone can help on this.

Comment: How about using `ssh -t userj@jumpbox ssh userf@finalhost`? Note that this is really just two `ssh` connections stuck end-to-end, so things like port forwarding will require extra work, sftp won't work through it, etc.